# How are these three approaches of defining a function different?

Tags: scala, methods, anonymous-function

In Scala, I found there are three ways to create the function, but I could hardly find their difference in behavior when I use them as a function.

```
scala> def incImplicit(x : Int) = x + 1
incImplicit: (x: Int)Int

scala> def incImplicit(x : Int): Int =  x + 1
incImplicit: (x: Int)Int

scala> def incAnonymous = ((x : Int) => x + 1)
incAnonymous: Int => Int
```

Comment: As indicated by the REPL, there is no difference between the first and second declaration, both are `(x: Int)Int`

Comment: For the gory details of the difference between your second and third choices, take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)

Answer (score 3):

This is a method with a single parameter `Int` named `x`, that returns an `Int` (x + 1) where the return type of `Int` is inferred by the compiler.

```
def incImplicit(x: Int) = x + 1
```

This is the same exact method as above, except the return type is explicit, and not inferred.

```
def incImplicit(x: Int): Int =  x + 1
```

This is a *parameterless method* that *returns* a `Function1[Int, Int]` (which is a function with one `Int` parameter that returns an `Int`).

```
def incAnonymous = ((x : Int) => x + 1)
```

i.e. the long signature looks like this:

```
def incAnonymous: Function1[Int, Int] = ((x : Int) => x + 1)
```

Or

```
def incAnonymous: Int => Int = ((x : Int) => x + 1)
```

---

Functionally, they are pretty much the same. If an `Int => Int` is required as a parameter, say for `def map(f: Int => Int)`, they will all work. When calling `map(incImplicit)`, the first two (which are the same exact method, anyway) will be implicitly converted to functions by *eta-expansion*. `map(incAnonymous)` will already have the correct signature, and would require no conversion.

`incImplicit(x)` and `incAnonymous(x)` will always return the same result for any `x`. The only difference is that `incImplicit` is one method call, and `incAnonymous` is a method call that returns a function, and *then* the `apply` method of the returned function is invoked. Generally, you would not have a method that returns a function unless you had a very good reason to do so.